# Prove $n+1$ items in $n$ buckets implies some bucket has $2$ items.

Tags: combinatorics

How would you formulate and formally prove (from a minimal set of axioms) the following statement is true?

> For all positive integers $n$, if $n+1$ items are placed into $n$ buckets, than one of the buckets must contain $2$ or more items.

Comment: It depends entirely on what axioms are available.

Comment: Are you aware that this is known as the “pigeonhole principle”? Searching for that term might give you some useful information.

Comment: From the standard axioms of the reals, my argument might go something like this:

Assume not. Then each bucket has at most 1 item, implying that there are at most ($n$ buckets)(at most 1 item in each) = $n$ items.

If that's all you were looking for, then this is called the finite pigeonhole principle, or the box principle, or the socks and drawers principle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Induction will do it. If you have $n+1$ items in $n$ buckets, with no more than one item per bucket, remove one nonempty bucket along with the item in it to be left with the exact same situation with $n$ replaced by $n-1$. Clearly, the case $n=0$ is impossible.

Comment: I could have written it out more formally, but some work needs to be left to the asker of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that each bucket has at most 1 item. There are n buckets. So, n buckets have at most n items but that is a contradiction, since there are n+1 items in total.